# Not Heated Build Plate Glue Amount and Dry Duration

Tags: desktop-printer, build-plate

**Background:**

I am using the Flux Delta 3d Printer, and it arrived with a glue stick. Now on their forums it said to apply 2 layers of glue and let it dry, there's supposed to be a link there on how long it should dry. However that link is broken.

**My question:**

On a not heated bed, how much glue-stick should I apply and for how long should I let it dry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a fellow Flux Delta owner, I can answer this question with certainty. Two layers is sufficient. Be sure to consider the size of the model being printed and the additional area covered if you are using skirts or rafts.

If you apply the glue stick at the moment you turn on the printer, it will be dry enough to work properly. The printer "uses time" to initialize and to calibrate which provides enough drying time. You will also "use time" to load the software and import the model.

It is not necessary to remove the glue from the plate after a print. For succeeding model printing, ensure that you've filled in the areas missing glue from removing the previous model.

You will want to remove the glue (hot water works good, but the build plate gets hot!) when you feel that the glue build-up changes the texture of the bottom layers.

You may have already learned from the forums that you print on the non-grid side of the build plate.

Comment: Thanks so much! That really helped a lot! Can I just as you, did you print out the tutorial print? Because mine came out looking quite weird and uneven...

Comment: I never did perform a tutorial print. I'm not sure where it is located.

Comment: From Flux Studio, under the help section, there was the tutorial